# Query three tables outputs nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have three tables as shown in the screenshot below:
[image: dataset]

But when I want to perform the following query, i get no results, even though there is data in all three tables:

[image: query]

Here is the generated code:

```
SELECT Clients.ClientID, Clients.FirstName, Clients.Surname, Clients.Internal, Clients.Organisation, Clients.LandlineNo, Clients.MobileNo, Clients.Address1, Clients.Town, 
              Clients.Postcode, Clients.Email, Clients.NHS, Clients.PurchaseOrderNumber, Bookings.Date, Bookings.Timebegan, Bookings.Timefinished, Bookings.Price, 
              Bookings.Repeats, Bookings.Rweeks, Bookings.Rdays, Bookings.Rmonths, Bookings.Occurrences, Rooms.Roomname
FROM     Clients INNER JOIN
              Bookings ON Clients.ClientID = Bookings.ClientID INNER JOIN
              Rooms ON Bookings.RoomID = Rooms.RoomID
```

Comment: Since you are using inner joins all of the tables need to contain data.  Try changing the joins to left outer joins and see if you get the results you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try

SELECT *
FROM     Clients LEFT OUTER JOIN
         Bookings ON Clients.ClientID = Bookings.ClientID 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Rooms ON Bookings.RoomID = Rooms.RoomID
```

See [Visual Explanation of SQL Join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) to better understand what to use

There are also some other approaches if performance is an issue.